# Should I create a extra relation-table when I have two columns in one table referencing to one column in another table

Tags: database-design, normalization, best-practices

My problem is best explained by example:

Suppose I have a database about chess games and players.

Which one of the following structures should I choose

Option 1)

```
player (player_id,name... etc)
game (game_id,date... etc)
game_player (game_id,player_id,white)
```

where `game_player.white` is True/False depending if the player was playing black or white

Option 2)

```
game (game_id,black_player,white_player,date... etc)
player (player_id,name... etc)
```

---

I think Option 2) is the best because I know that every game has exactly 2 players and one of them is black and one is white.  However, somehow the queries in this setup don't feel so natural to me. Even in simple queries I have to join to player table twice and need conditions like `game.black_player = player.player_id`

Option 1) feels good because it's immediately clear where each column is  referencing. However, otherwise I don't like option 1) so much.

- So which one is the best practice and why? Or is there even better Option 3)?
- If I choose option 2) how should I name the black_player and white_player columns to be clear that they are referencing to the player table.

Hopefully my question makes sense.

I realize that this is a very basic question but I can't stop thinking about this and didn't find anything by searching.

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely choose option 2. A game of chess is between *exactly two* players.

Option 1 allows a game with 0, 1, 2, 3 or more players, while the data model in option 2 (assuming `not null` on the two player columns) means that you will never have these data inconsistencies. Just remember to also add the check constraint `black_player != white_player`.